# how to get the math operators strings from module `operator` in python

Tags: python, string, math, operators

Take `operator.add` for example:

```
>>>import operator as op
>>>op.add(1,2)       #means 1 + 2
3
>>>op.add.__name__
'add'
```

I want sort of:

```
>>>op.add.math_str
"+"
```

Can I get all those math string `"+", "-", ">"...` module `operator` supported runtime?

EDIT:

```
>>> [eval(x) for x in [".".join(("op",x,"__doc__")) for x in dir(op)]]
['abs(a) -- Same as abs(a).',
 'add(a, b) -- Same as a + b.',
 'and_(a, b) -- Same as a & b.',
 'concat(a, b) -- Same as a + b, for a and b sequences.',
 'contains(a, b) -- Same as b in a (note reversed operands).',
 'delitem(a, b) -- Same as del a[b].',
 'delslice(a, b, c) -- Same as del a[b:c].',
 'div(a, b) -- Same as a / b when __future__.division is not in effect.',
 'str(object) -> string\n\nReturn a nice string representation of the object.\nIf the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.',
```

above code can list most operators strings, is that means I can list strings with re module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Build your own dictionary.

Comment: Here are the the operator docs: http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [following table from tutorial](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html?highlight=operator#mapping-operators-to-functions) to build your own mappings dictionary only once and then simply use it whenever you will need it.